# Why does this div shift down when content is added?

Tags: css

I have a 5x5 grid and when i add content to the div, it is shifted down. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

[image]

codepen example: [Risk Matrix](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/yzxFr)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the codepen example is now working as it should.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add this to vertical-align: top and margin-top: 3px;

```
.r5 > div, .r4 > div, .r3 > div, .r2 > div, .r1 > div {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
}
```

I believe its because content pushes the dom out of empty space.

**HERE is the answer why this happends.**

In a inline-level (inline-block) you have to specify the vertical alignment of text. So in essence without setting where the vertical alignment is content is placed in its default which is baseline. This is why your text offsetted your layout.

Comment: Hope that was helpful. Here is the supporting research. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 2):

If you set:

```
.r5, .r4, .r3, .r2, .r1 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; <-- this
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

It aligns properly.

Comment: you forgot to add margin spacing, now they stack with no spacing.

Comment: It happends, you got it before I did, just saw you didnt have one thing. I give you +1 for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow:hidden` on the `<div />` elements should fix it as it will make the elements ignore any margin or padding that inner-nodes create that overflow the containing element.

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mDonw