# Why is my HTML div not displayed correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am writing a small website for old web browsers, so I have to use old-school tags.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#left-pane,
#right-pane {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20em;
  height: 40em;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-pane">
  <div class="conf">
    <p>First select</p>
    <select class="value">
      <option id="fr">France</option>
      <option id="ch">Suisse</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="conf">
    <p>Second select</p>
    <div class="value">
      <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Oui" />Oui
      <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Non" />Non
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right-pane">
  <p>Third</p>
  <div id="goods">
    <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresAnimalerie" Value="Accessoires Animalerie" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresChaussures" Value="Accessoires Chaussures" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I am running into a simple problem, but I cannot figure what's wrong; I am missing something...

I don't understand why my right pane is shifted down. 
I made both panes inline-block, so they should both be side by side, on the same line.
But instead, I am seeing this:

[image]

And it is rendered the same in Chrome and Firefox (latest versions).

I know I could do this some other way with float, but I would like to know what's wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005314/why-does-this-div-shift-down-when-content-is-added

Comment: Nothing is incorrect with your implementation, you are observing standard behaviour of the "step-down effect" of *inline-block* elements. To circumvent this, you just need to declare a `vertical-align` property with the value of `top`.

Comment: Besides `float:left` or `vertical-align:top`, which both fix the issue, another *fix* is `overflow:hidden` on the two boxes. As to why, it's how block level elements work. I suppose Younel's answer kind of answers it, but still not complete, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property to `top`, that lines up elements at the top of the parent element, there is a good article [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/) explains how `vertical-align` property works.

**Working Demo:**

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

#left-pane, #right-pane {
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
 width: 10em;
 height: 40em;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-pane">
    <div class="conf">
        <p>First select</p>
        <select class="value">
            <option id="fr">France</option>
            <option id="ch">Suisse</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="conf">
        <p>Second select</p>
        <div class="value">
            <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Oui" />Oui
            <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Non" />Non
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right-pane">
    <p>Third</p>
    <div id="goods">
        <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresAnimalerie" Value="Accessoires Animalerie" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresChaussures" Value="Accessoires Chaussures" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    #left-pane, #right-pane {
        border: 1px solid white;
        float:left;
        color:white;
        margin-right:0.4em;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20em;
        height: 40em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left-pane">
            <div class="conf">
                <p>First select</p>
                <select class="value">
                    <option id="fr">France</option>
                    <option id="ch">Suisse</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="conf">
                <p>Second select</p>
                <div class="value">
                    <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Oui" />Oui
                    <input type="radio" name="known" Value="Non" />Non
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-pane">
            <p>Third</p>
            <div id="goods">
                <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresAnimalerie" Value="Accessoires Animalerie" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="AccessoiresChaussures" Value="Accessoires Chaussures" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

While others have suggested using `vertical-align: top;`, which works for your purposes, I found that `float: left;` also works. `float: left` is my go-to for doing columns, or anything that needs to be side-by-side. I added a `color: white` and a `margin-right: 0.4em` to the properties, to make the example look nicer, but this is my own personal preference.

Comment: That's what I already suggested in my post